# SQL Server fetch alias name for query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please check fiddle: [myFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184dc/1)

Query:

```
create table Emp(empId int primary key, EmpName varchar(50),MngrID int)

insert into Emp(empId,EmpName,MngrID)values(1,'A',2)
insert into Emp(empId,EmpName,MngrID)values(2,'B',null)
```

A has mngr B but A has no mngr, so while fetching the record from query it shows me:

```
EmpId           EmpName     MngrName(alias MngrName)
 1                 A            B
 2                 B            null
```

How to fetch the above data using a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason it doesn't work in SQLFiddle, but i ran it in my own instance of SQL Server to verify it does work:

```
SELECT  e1.EmpID, e1.EmpName, e2.EmpName
FROM  emp e1 LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e2 
ON e1.MngrID = e2.EmpID
```

Basically, you're doing a 'self join' by declaring two instances of the table (e1 and e2), and then joining the first instance's MngrID to the second instance's EmpID.

Answer (score 1):

You need to LEFT JOIN table to itself:

```
select A.empID, A.empName, b.empName as mgrName
from emp A left join emp B on  A.mngrID = b.empID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/184dc/8

Answer (score 0):

select empId,EmpName,(SELECT EmpName FROM emp WHERE MngrID = amp1.MngrID) AS Manager from emp as amp1